# How to implement the ability to hang out event handler when creating an item?

Tags: javascript

I have a `createEelement()` function.

With her, I will create HTML elements.

Function code:

```
function createElement(tagName, options, ...children) {
  const { classNames = [], attributes = {} } = options;
  const elem = document.createElement(tagName);

  for (let i = 0; i < classNames.length; i++) {
    elem.classList.add(classNames[i]);
  }

  for (const attributePair of Object.entries(attributes)) {
    const [attributeKey, attributeValue] = attributePair;
    elem.setAttribute(attributeKey, attributeValue);
  }

  elem.append(...children);

  return elem;
}
```

The function allows you to create items, hang classes and attributes. And also encourage all children to the item. Allows you to do it immediately when creating. I need to expand this feature in such a way that the event handlers can also be mounted. I plan to implement this in the `options` object.

My question is how can this be done? Considering that listeners may be more than one ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve your problem, you could have an array of object, with the names of the events, the callbacks and the options of the event :

```js
const listeners = [{
    name: "onclick",
    callback: (e) => e.preventDefault(),
    options: {},
}];
```

(This is just an example)
Here is the result :

```js
function createElement(tagName, options, ...children) {
  const { classNames = [], attributes = {}, listeners = {} } = options;
  const elem = document.createElement(tagName);

  for (let i = 0; i < classNames.length; i++) {
    elem.classList.add(classNames[i]);
  }

  for (const listener of listeners) {
    elem.addEventListener(...listener);
  }

  for (const attributePair of Object.entries(attributes)) {
    const [attributeKey, attributeValue] = attributePair;
    elem.setAttribute(attributeKey, attributeValue);
  }

  elem.append(...children);

  return elem;
}
```

**Bonus**
Here are some factorisation improvments :

```js
function createElement(tagName, options, ...children) {
  const { classNames = [], attributes = {}, listeners = {} } = options;
  const elem = document.createElement(tagName);

  // using a for...of loop
  for (const className of classNames) {
    elem.classList.add(className);
  }

  for (const listener of listeners) {
    elem.addEventListener(...listener);
  }

  // destructuring instead of recreating two variables
  for (const attributePair of Object.entries(attributes)) {
    elem.setAttribute(...attributePair);
  }

  elem.append(...children);

  return elem;
}
```

PS : I didn't tested this code so it might not work, tell me if something is wrong.